# Adobe AIR After Build Issue

Tags: actionscript-3, air, animate-cc

I created a **Desktop AIR** in Adobe **Animate CC** 2017 with **AIR 23**, when **Test** everything works, after **Build** in my pc everything works, when test to **VirtualBox** (Application with runtime embedded) it run but some features like buttons events and url events doesn't works, what is problem?

Comment: Check if you address stage in any of the constructors. There might be differences between the initialization process on PC and in a virtual environment that cause post-initialization add to stage of your main class, and you get nulls hidden by some things not working because it's not properly initialized.

Comment: what is stage and how i could check it? my program is not complex, some UI and some code for work with external URL API.

Comment: I checked in another Laptop it still doesn't work properly, just in my pc everything work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After review codes and test for many times i found correct issue, when a hidden runtime error occurred some related part doesn't works properly, I used `try()` `catch()` for handle errors and external video playback instead embedded, now build works on other computers without problem.

Comment: Upped for self debug efforts :)